# What would happen if two entangled particles collided?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, collision, large-hadron-collider

Does that is even possible? I have almost zero knowledge in quantum physics, it is just a curiosity that popped in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They would create another pair of entangled particles.

Comment: Hmmm, i see.. just to know more, how would it happen?

Comment: Entangled particles stay entangled even if they interact.